# Taking a photo using Cordova via Backbone.js View

Tags: javascript, android, backbone.js, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to take a photo using the Cordova API (in IBM Worklight) but the success callback never seems to fire (when I use the same code outside of Backbone.js it works perfectly).

This is my view file:

```
var app = app || {};

app.WalletView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: '#page',

    template: Handlebars.getTemplate( 'wallet' ),

    events: {
        'click #camera-snap': 'getPhoto'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },

    // render library by rendering each book in its collection
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html( this.template() );
        return this;
    },

    getPhoto: function(e) {
        var $img = this.$el.find('img#camera-image');
        console.info('Taking Photo');
        /*
         | BASED ON: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11928792/633056
         */
        navigator.camera.getPicture(
            function(data) {
                $img.show();
                alert(data);  // <-- success alert
                //img.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + data;
                $img.attr('src', "data:image/jpeg;base64," + data);
                $('#camera-status').text("Success");
            },
            function(e) {
                console.log("Error getting picture: " + e);
                $('camera-status').innerHTML = e;
                //dom.byId('camera-image').style.display = "none";
            },
            // must be DATA_URL to return the data for future use
            {quality: 50, destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL, sourceType : navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA}
        );
    }

});
```

This is how I initiate that view:

```
'showWallet': function() {
    new app.WalletView();
},
```

This is the HTML template:

```
<h1>Camera POC</h1>
<p>Camera Status: <i id="camera-status"></i></p>
<input type="submit" value="Take Picture" id="camera-snap">
<img src="" id="camera-image" style="width: 80%;">
```

Clicking on the `input#camera-snap` button brings up the native camera interface. I can then take a photo and (on Android) click the tick button (in the native interface). However, when I am returned to the Hybrid app nothing happens.

I would expect the `alert()` in my success callback to popup with with a huge string of BASE64 data (as it does when not within Backbone.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean "the success callback never seems to fire"? I'm not sure at what point you are seeing problems.

Comment: You're right that is a rubbish initial question. I have added more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you add a console.log($img) in your success callback right before the $img.show() call like below?

```
var $img = this.$el.find('img#camera-image');
        console.info('Taking Photo');

        navigator.camera.getPicture(
            function(data) {
                console.log($img);     // <-- new console.log
                $img.show();
                alert(data);  
                ....
            },
            function(e) {
                ....
            },
            ....
        );
    }
```

It could be that thie $img variable isn't visible in the scope of your success callback and so your javascript dies before it gets to the alert.

Comment: No problem. If the solution above helped, please mark the answer as the accepted answer. It helps us to track unanswered questions.