# How to implement Barcode Scanner in Multiple Platforms on IBM Worklight?

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst, barcode-scanner, worklight-studio, multi-device-hybrid-apps

How to implement barcode scanner in Hybrid applications, which i want to support it for android/ios/bb/windows platforms in IBM Worklight.

Comment: Please provide some implementation you did

Comment: Here is the source code for implementing barcode scanner in JS https://gist.github.com/tobytailor/421369

Comment: Hi Mustafa sabir, When i click on Barcode Scanner Button automatically  it should open the Mobile camera and the barcode should be scanned and i have to store it in local DB.

Comment: Refer this to understand how to use camera to get picture in worklight  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11900361/how-to-open-native-camera-in-ibm-worklight . Then you can pass the image you get to the source provided here https://gist.github.com/tobytailor/421369 and display the output on the page.

Comment: I am able to open the camera,Now how to implement barcode scanning and where can i use get_barcode_from_image.js in Worklight project.

Comment: i am able to scan the Barcode by using Native methods , here is the link to Read the barcode Values " https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/WASFAQs/entry/using_a_barcode_scanner_with_worklight?lang=en ", Now i am going to store these values in DB and append that to a listview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some third party libraries to achieve cross platform bar code scanning using camera.

- [Zbar](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/download.html) - it is free and you can use it with [cordova](http://blog.infoentropy.com/use_zbar_barcode_reader_with_phonegap) also.
- [RedLaser](http://redlaser.com/) mainly used for enterprise apps and it is not free.

If you dont want to use above libraries you need to create a [cordova](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html) plugin to capture the image and read the barcode from image which you captured. for more into [link](https://github.com/EddieLa/BarcodeReader)

Comment: Can you provide me for Multiple platforms supported Barcode scanner cordova plugin.  The Zbar cordova supports only for IOS, i need to implement this barcode functionality in multiple mobile platforms.

Comment: Failed to Build the BarcodeScanner in IBM Worklight Hybrid application, getting "cordova/plugin/barcodescanner" not found Error Message.